# ASP.NET 4.0 Charting - How can one display a explanatory message in the chart area when the databound query returns no results?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, charts

I have a .Net 4 Chart Control bound to stored proc.  For some customer selected queries the chart will be empty.  I would like to display a "No data" message in the empty charting area so customers understand why the chart is empty.  I haven't been able to find any information about how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by doing this in my code behind:

```
If MySQLReader.Read Then
            Chart1.DataSource = MySQLReader
            Chart1.Series("Series1").XValueMember = "XValue"
            Chart1.Series("Series1").YValueMembers = "YValue"
            Chart1.Height = 500
            Chart1.Width = 750
            Chart1.DataBind()
            LBLError.Text = ""
        Else
            Chart1.Visible = False
            LBLError.Text = "Your search did not match any records in the database"
            MySQLReader.Close()
            MyConn.Close()
        End If
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks James.  Changing the Visible setting was the insight I was missing.  That gives me the UX I want.